# 'ClientDocument' object has no attribute 'url' при создании Custom hyperlinked fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Пытаюсь сделать как описано [тут](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-hyperlinked-fields), но ничего не получается.
Вот что имею:

**model.py**

```
class Client(Timestamps):
    full_name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Full name'))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Client')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Clients')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.initials)

class ClientDocument(Timestamps):
    description = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Description'))
    issue_date = models.DateField(verbose_name=_('Date of issue'))
    client = models.ForeignKey('Client', verbose_name=_('Client'))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Identity document")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Identity documents")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.description)
```

**vievs.py**

```
class ClientDocumentViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def retrieve(self, request, client=None, pk=None):
        queryset = ClientDocument.objects.filter(client__company=request.user.company)
        document = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)

        serializer = DocumentRetrieveSerializer(instance=document, context={'request': request})

        return Response({'data': serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**serializers.py**

```
classMultiplePKHyperlinkedIdentityField(serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField):
        view_name = 'clientdocument-detail'
        queryset = ClientDocument.objects.all()

        def get_url(self, obj, view_name, request, format):
            url_kwargs = {
                'client': obj.client.pk,
                'pk': obj.pk
            }
            return reverse(view_name, kwargs=url_kwargs, request=request, format=format)

        def get_object(self, view_name, view_args, view_kwargs):
            lookup_kwargs = {
                'client_id': view_kwargs['client'],
                'pk': view_kwargs['pk']
            }
            return self.get_queryset().get(**lookup_fields)

    class DocumentRetrieveSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
        url = MultiplePKHyperlinkedIdentityField()

        class Meta:
            model = ClientDocument
            fields = ('id', 'description', 'issue_date', 'url')
```

**urls.py**

```
api_v1_patterns = [
    url(r'^clients/(?P<client>[0-9]+)/documents/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/', ClientDocumentViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'}), name='clientdocument-detail'),
]
```

Выдает вот такую ошибку:

**AttributeError at /api/v1/clients/3/documents/3/**

'ClientDocument' object has no attribute 'url'

```
Traceback:

File "/media/veracrypt1/psm_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/media/veracrypt1/psm_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/media/veracrypt1/psm_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/media/veracrypt1/psm_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
  87.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/media/veracrypt1/psm_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  466.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/media/veracrypt1/psm_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  463.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/media/veracrypt1/psm_venv/psm/api/views.py" in retrieve
  204.         return Response({'data': serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

File "/media/veracrypt1/psm_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  503.         ret = super(Serializer, self).data

File "/media/veracrypt1/psm_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  239.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)

File "/media/veracrypt1/psm_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  463.                 attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)

File "/media/veracrypt1/psm_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py" in get_attribute
  146.         return get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)

File "/media/veracrypt1/psm_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py" in get_attribute
  80.                 instance = getattr(instance, attr)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/v1/clients/3/documents/3/
Exception Value: 'ClientDocument' object has no attribute 'url'
```

Спасибо заранее всем!!!